# How to register custom html tags in Resharper?

Tags: html, resharper, custom-tags

I would like to use custom tags in my html files to include custom knockout components [[1](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html)]:

```
<like-widget params="value: userRating"></like-widget>
```

I added the tag to the VisualStudio html formatting settings:

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML (Web Forms) > Formatting > Tag
>   Specific Options

Resharper still does not recognize the custom tag and gives the warning

> Cannot resolve tag "like-widget"

How do I tell Resharper to allow that specific tag without disabling the unknown tag warning? Is there some sort of setting file where I can register custom html tags?

Related article:

[How to add custom HTML Tags to Visual Studio and Avoid Squiggly Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715897/how-to-add-custom-html-tags-to-visual-studio-and-avoid-squiggly-lines)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible right now - there is a related ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-434190.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to Disable the Inspection for Unknown HTML Tags as I indicated here:

[Can I stop ReSharper objecting to Ionic HTML tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32157649/can-i-stop-resharper-objecting-to-ionic-html-tags/42503498#42503498)

Comment: *without disabling the unknown tag warning*